# Lua-cjson -> require("cjson") successful, then errors when calling cjson.encode

Tags: json, lua, luarocks

I'm trying to encode/decode JSON in Lua using CJSON. I downloaded lua-cjson using Luarocks (http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html).

In the Lua interpreter, I'm using an example from the cjson manual:

```
> local cjson = require "cjson"
> value = { true, { foo = "bar" } } 
> json_text = cjson.encode(value)
stdin:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'cjson')
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I know that cjson is being found, because if I were to do ' require "foobar" ', Lua would error. It's just not able to use the module. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Each line in an interactive session is a separate chunk. So, the local variable created in line 1 no longer exists in the next lines. Note how the error message mentions a *global* variable. Try removing `local`.

Comment: Thank you. Writing a Lua script with the above code worked, even with 'local' included.

Comment: In a script, you are supposed to use `local` and avoid setting a global. I know it's confusing, but unfortunately due to this limitation of the interpreter, you are forced to use two different programming styles whether you're in the command line or a script.